# Basic Bash script exiting prematurely. Worked fine until a half hour ago

Tags: bash

I have having an interesting issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a basic script that pulls configuration information and just redirects it to a file:

`cat /etc/something > 1`

`cat /etc/something-else > 2`

As soon as my data gather is finished, I run a "parser" that presents info about the check:

```
#58

id="RHEL-06-000001"
ruleid="The system must require passwords to contain at least one special character."
if grep -G [a-z] 1; then
    ocredit=`cat 1 | grep -v "^#" | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [ "$ocredit" -le -1 ]; then
            result="Not A Finding"
            todo="None"
    else
            result="Open"
            todo="The current value is $ocredit. This is less than the minimum requirement of -     1."
    fi
else
    result="Open"
    todo="The option is not configured"
fi
echo "$id, $ruleid, $result, $todo" >> Findings.csv

#59

id="RHEL-06-000002"
ruleid="The system must require passwords to contain at least one lowercase alphabetic     character."
if grep -G [a-z] 2; then
    lcredit=`cat 2 | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'`
    if [ "$lcredit" -le -1 ]; then
            result="Not A Finding"
            todo="None"
    else
            result="Open"
            todo="The current value is $lcredit. This is less than the minimum requirement of -1."
    fi
else
    result="Open"
    todo="The system is not configured to require at least one lowercase alphabetical charatcer in passwords."
echo "$id, $ruleid, $result, $todo" >> Findings.csv
```

Or something remotely close to that.

I have roughly 250 of these checks happening but my code is runs the first 58 and then stops and no longer redirects content to the checks.csv.

I do get an error after the script finishes prematurely, stating 
`./checker.sh: line 2898: syntax error: unexpected end of file` 
which is the end of my file, but I can't seem to figure out how it is escaping to that point in the script.

The kicker, this all worked until about a half hour ago and it has be stumped.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Try adding quotes around `[a-z]`. I bet you created a file in the current directory with a single-letter name.

Comment: Line 2898? That's one hell of a script...

Comment: Lol, has to be a script. No compiled code allowed.

Comment: I'll try the quotes, it's been a long night

Comment: Quotes didn't make a difference. I have lots of other sections of code without it that run fine.

Comment: My file structure is the numbers 1 - 500something. I use the `grep -G [a-z]` to see if there is anything in the file at all, otherwise, no need to waste time on it.

Comment: I suppose we have to assume you don't use a VCS (version control system) while developing — so you don't have any backups of the working version?  Note to you for future reference: save working versions somehow — and a VCS is a good way of saving versions, even while you're developing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You would be correct. I am scripting on the fly and just ran into the issue. It would behoove me to implement something. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I used to use RCS; for single files, it still works fine.  I usually use `git` these days. Anything is better than nothing, though.

Comment: I'll give git a try. I've heard good things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `fi` after your second-last line:

```
else
    result="Open"
    todo="The system is not configured to require at least one lowercase alphabetical charatcer in passwords."
## HERE ##
echo "$id, $ruleid, $result, $todo" >> Findings.csv
```

That could potentially cause problems for the bash parser when encountered, causing an EOF error when `bash` tries to find the missing `fi`.

Comment: Fantastic. I just needed a second set of eyes. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

That probably means you've got an unclosed `if` statement or similar. Bash reads simple commands on-demand, but when it comes upon a complex statement like that, it wants to read the whole `if` statement and its contents. If it then comes upon an EOF while still trying to read to the end of it, it will give you that error.

Comment: So it may not being an issue with the code that is presented, but rather the code that runs before it. I do have several "complex" commands in this script. Lots of places for it to go astray.